# Sparse Data Frame Alternative

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

```
vectorizer = tfidf()
x = vectorizer.fit_transform(clean_articles)
x.shape

x_df = pd.SparseDataFrame(x, columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names(),index=range(len(clean_articles)))
```

As Sparse Dataframe is discontinued, how can I replace this code?

Comment: Related: [How do I create a SparseDataFrame in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65324029/9840637)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a SparseDataFrame in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25358381/how-do-i-create-a-sparsedataframe-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(
    x, 
    columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names_out(), 
    index=range(len(clean_articles))
)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).